# How to make a Clojure function take a variable number of parameters?

Tags: function, clojure, lisp, procedure

I'm learning Clojure and I'm trying to define a function that take a variable number of parameters (a *variadic* function) and sum them up (yep, just like the + procedure). However, I don´t know how to implement such function

Everything I can do is:

`(defn sum [n1, n2] (+ n1 n2))`

Of course this function takes two parameteres and two parameters only. Please teach me how to make it accept (and process) an undefined number of parameters.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

In general, non-commutative case you can use [apply](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply):

```
(defn sum [& args] (apply + args))
```

Since addition is commutative, something like this should work too:

```
(defn sum [& args] (reduce + args))
```

`&`  causes `args` to be bound to the remainder of the argument list (in this case the whole list, as there's nothing to the left of `&`).

Obviously defining sum like that doesn't make sense, since instead of:

```
(sum a b c d e ...)
```

you can just write:

```
(+ a b c d e ....)
```

Comment: Yes, doesn´t make sence, but it is a good illustration to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @soulcheck: is there a way to pass a `seq` to your sum function. For example : (sum '(1 2 3)) and the result is 6 ?

Comment: @avichalp that would be another function. just remove `&` from either version

Comment: @soulcheck: No. I mean using the same function signature. I am a newbie in clojure hence I am able to put my point clearly here. What I would like to know is in python I can use *args and if a function is defined such that it takes *args (eg `def fn(*args): pass`) I can call it by giving a list like fn(*list_of_args). Can I do the same thing in clojure ?

Comment: @avichalp the call to `def fn(*args): pass` wouldn't be `fn([1,2,3])` but `fn(1,2,3)` (obviously depending what you want to do exactly, but I'm trying to follow the spirit here)

Comment: @soulcheck: In python I can pass a list with an star prepended to it like   `fn(*[1, 2, 3])` it will be equivalent to `fn(1, 2, 3)`. Is this possible in clojure ?

Comment: @avichalp the & creates a seq out of the arguments passed to the function. If you were to pass a seq, you would be passing a seq of seqs and apply would not be able to evaluate the seq because it expects a clojure.lang.Number type based on the arguments asked for by +

Comment: What @avichalp is asking about is Python's star operator, which [unpacks a list argument](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/#Asterisks_for_unpacking_into_function_call) into individual arguments in a function call. The answer is no, Clojure doesn't have that, you would use `apply` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10802391/165673.

Answer (score 34):

Yehoanathan mentions arity overloading but does not provide a direct example. Here's what he's talking about:

```
(defn special-sum
  ([] (+ 10 10))
  ([x] (+ 10 x))
  ([x y] (+ x y)))
```

`(special-sum)` => `20`

`(special-sum 50)` => `60`

`(special-sum 50 25)` => `75`

Comment: Also works with lambdas: `(fn  ([] (+ 10 10))  ([x] (+ 10 x))  ([x y] (+ x y)))`

Answer (score 17):

```
 (defn my-sum
  ([]  0)                         ; no parameter
  ([x] x)                         ; one parameter
  ([x y] (+ x y))                 ; two parameters
  ([x y & more]                   ; more than two parameters


    (reduce + (my-sum x y) more))
  )
```

Answer (score 11):

> `defn` is a macro that makes defining functions a little simpler.
>   Clojure supports arity overloading in a single function object,
>   self-reference, and variable-arity functions using `&`

From http://clojure.org/functional_programming

Answer (score 4):

```
(defn sum [& args]
  (print "sum of" args ":" (apply + args)))
```

This takes any number of arguments and add them up.

Comment: Duplicate of @soulcheck answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9242671/1327651