# How to destructure a vector for use as a function argument

Tags: clojure

In Python, you can pass a list or tuple to a function and have the function unpack the argument. How can I do that in Clojure? Here is some example Python code:

```
def f (a, b, c, *d):
    print "a: ", a
    print "b: ", b
    print "c: ", c
    print "d: ", d

f (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

print
v = (4, 5, 6)
f(1, 2, 3, *v)
```

result:

```
a:  1
b:  2
c:  3
d:  (4, 5, 6)

a:  1
b:  2
c:  3
d:  (4, 5, 6)
```

in my clojure code:

```
(defn f [a b c & d]
  (println "a: " a)
  (println "b: " b)
  (println "c: " c)
  (println "d: " d))

(f 1 2 3 4 5 6)

(println)
(def v [4 5 6])
(f 1 2 3 v)
```

result:

```
a:  1
b:  2
c:  3
d:  (4 5 6)

a:  1
b:  2
c:  3
d:  ([4 5 6])
```

the d have one element only, how can I let result as python code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clojure does not unpack arguments from a vector with a language feature, like Python does.

The closest thing to unpacking is function [apply](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/apply).

In this particular case:

```
(def v [4 5 6])
(apply f (concat [1 2 3] v))
```

Prints:

```
a:  1
b:  2
c:  3
d:  (4 5 6)
```

Comment: (apply f (concat [1 2 3] v)) is great, I can concat others: (apply f (concat [1 2 3] v [7 8 9]))

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness.

Say you have a function that takes a vector `[d1 d2 d3]` as an argument

```
(defn f
  [a b c [d1 d2 d3]]
  (println "a: " a)
  (println "b: " b)
  (println "c: " c)
  (println "d1: " d1)
  (println "d2: " d2)
  (println "d3: " d3))
```

This way we can take the first 3 items from the vector that is passed into the function `f` as `d1 d2 d3`. Calling the above function results in the following output:

```
=> (f 1 2 3 [6 7 8 9])
a:  1
b:  2
c:  3
d1:  6
d2:  7
d3:  8
```

Note that even though the vector contains 4 items, we only take the first 3.

Answer (score 0):

For any argument in Clojure, you can determine whether the argument is a scalar value or a sequence by using sequential? In the pseudo-code below,

```
(if (sequential? v)
   (do-something-because-it's-a-sequence v)
   (do-something-different-because-it's-not-a-sequence v))
```

So, in Clojure, you can accomplish the same task as in your Python example by determining whether you have a sequence or not.

Comment: to determining d element, use sequential? is better, (seq? [1 2 3]) => false