# Clojure "apply" throws ClassCastException in simple sum function

Tags: clojure

This function

```
(defn sum [& args] (apply + args))
```

should sum up all args sequence elements throws an exception. 
Why?

```
user> (defn sum [& args] (apply + args))
#'user/sum
user> (sum [1 2 3])
ClassCastException   java.lang.Class.cast (Class.java:2999)
user> (sum (range 1 10))
ClassCastException   java.lang.Class.cast (Class.java:2999)
```

(also used as example (which does not compile for me) in this question [How to make a Clojure function take a variable number of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242440/how-to-make-a-clojure-function-take-a-variable-number-of-parameters))

I'm using nrepl in Emacs 24.2 Live with Clojure 1.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify a function parameter with `& args`, that means that `args` will contain a list of all further function parameters. In this case, `sum` is getting a list of all of its parameters--but its parameter is *already* a list, so effectively what `sum` is doing here is

```
(apply + [[1 2 3]])
```

If you get rid of the `&` in your definition of `sum`'s parameters (so that the list is just `[args]`) you'll get what you want.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks :) It's obvious now :D

Comment: Glad to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If I've answered your question, you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking the outline of the checkmark next to my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. In Clojure variable arguments are lists itself

```
(sum 1 2 3)
```