# What is clojure's "doc" command printing out?

Tags: clojure

I'm a bit confused by clojure's `doc`.

The output is a specification of arguments, using the traditional [basic regular expression markup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts), which is:

- `*`: 0..n instances of the marked-up preceding element ("many")
- `?`: 0..1 instances of the marked-up preceding element ("optional")
- `+`: 1..n instances of the marked-up preceding element ("at least one")

Parentheses `()` and square brackets `[]` are, however, to be used "as given" to form the correct *expression* or *form*, and are not used for grouping of any regular expression elements.

And if there are several valid argument combinations, they are listed on several lines.

But observe for example the output for `(doc fn)`:

```
clojure.core/fn
  (fn name? [params*] exprs*)
  (fn name? ([params*] exprs*) +)
([& sigs])
Special Form
  params => positional-params* , or positional-params* & next-param
  positional-param => binding-form
  next-param => binding-form
  name => symbol

  Defines a function

  Please see http://clojure.org/special_forms#fn
  params => positional-params* , or positional-params* & next-param
  positional-param => binding-form
  next-param => binding-form
  name => symbol

  Defines a function
Spec
  args: (cat :fn-name (? simple-symbol?) :fn-tail (alt :arity-1 :clojure.core.specs.alpha/params+body :arity-n (+ (spec :clojure.core.specs.alpha/params+body))))
  ret: any?
nil
```

The first three lines make sense as:

1. Package and name of *var* or *special form*
2. A valid expression structure `(fn name? [params*] exprs*)`
3. Another possible expression structure `(fn name? ([params*] exprs*) +)`

But then there is a non-indented `([& sigs])`. What's that about?

The subsequent output also seems to be in need of cleanup. And what's the "Spec"?

For `(doc doc)`:

```
clojure.repl/doc
([name])
Macro
  Prints documentation for a var or special form given its name,
   or for a spec if given a keyword
nil
```

I don't understand the non-indented `([name])`.

Or let's try `(doc letfn)`:

```
clojure.core/letfn
  (letfn [fnspecs*] exprs*)
([fnspecs & body])
Special Form
  fnspec ==> (fname [params*] exprs) or (fname ([params*] exprs)+)

  Takes a vector of function specs and a body, and generates a set of
  bindings of functions to their names. All of the names are available
  in all of the definitions of the functions, as well as the body.
  fnspec ==> (fname [params*] exprs) or (fname ([params*] exprs)+)

  Takes a vector of function specs and a body, and generates a set of
  bindings of functions to their names. All of the names are available
  in all of the definitions of the functions, as well as the body.
nil
```

Again the meaning of `([fnspecs & body])` is unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the parameter lists for the functions.

From [the source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/841fa60b41bc74367fb16ec65d025ea5bde7a617/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4479):

[image: Code from the definition of the 'fn' macro]

`([& sigs])` says that it takes a variadic list of "(sig)natures". "Signature" in this case is referring to the example forms on the previous lines. Either `([params] body)` for creating a function with a single parameter list, or a list of `(([params] body) ([other-params] body)` to create a function with multiple parameter lists.

The `doc` one is just saying that `doc` accepts a `name` as an argument.

Finally, `letfn` is saying that it takes a "`fnspecs`" vector, and a variadic `body` of expressions. You can see that in how it's used:

```
(letfn [(some-function [param] ; The vector on these two lines is "fnspecs"
                        (println param))]
  (println "PRINTING!") ; These two lines are grouped into "body"
  (some-function 1))
```

---

It has an outer set of parenthesis because it's showing a list of all the available parameter lists. `doc` shows `([name])` (a list of one vector) because it only has one valid parameter list. If you look at the docs for a function like `max` though:

```
clojure.core/max
([x] [x y] [x y & more])
  Returns the greatest of the nums.
```

Its listing multiple parameter lists because `max` has multiple arities.

---

As for why `letfn` shows `([fnspec & body])`, that's the [way that it's defined in the source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/841fa60b41bc74367fb16ec65d025ea5bde7a617/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6471):

[image: Code from the definition of the 'letfn' macro]

`fnspecs` is the first parameter, and any arguments supplied after that are grouped into the `body` var-arg list. You may need to look over [Clojure's var-arg syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9242440/3000206).

Comment: Ya, sorry, I had it right the first time. I'm taking a break from Clojure to learn C and some knowledge evidently fell out of my head. And adding more explanation on those bits.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Updated. Let me know if that clears it up. If not, what about the syntax are you asking about for the latter?

Comment: Yes, I get it now. Thanks! Good luck with C, that's must be a reverse cultural shock after Clojure.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Ya, taking 10 lines to reverse a string, then needing to deal with the allocated memory is a PITA. It certainly isn't expressive or terse.

Comment: The point is that the non-indented `([& sigs])`, `([name])`, `([fnspecs & body])` are the actual parameter declarations, _enclosed in parentheses_ by the `doc` routine. Subtle.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Yes, it matches the definition format. Look up the definition of `max`.